# How to find $g(x)$ without having boundaries?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Question:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be rvs with
> $$
> f(i,j)
>  = \mathbb{P}[X=i,Y=j]
>  = \frac{1}{e} \left(\frac{1}{2^{i+1}} \frac{1}{j!}\right)
> $$
> and $i,j$ are natural numbers.
>
> 1. Prove that $\mathbb{P}[X=i]=1/2^{i+1}$
> 2. Prove $Y$ has a Poisson distribution

For a I was thinking of finding $g(x)$ but I don't have the boundaries of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is a typo in your question. The correct joint pmf is the following

$$\mathbb{P}[X=i;Y=j]=e^{-1}\frac{1}{2^{i+1}j!}$$

To find the marginal X sum in Y and viceversa

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[X=i]=e^{-1}\frac{1}{2^{i+1}}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j!}=e^{-1}\frac{1}{2^{i+1}}e=\frac{1}{2^{i+1}}$$

$$\mathbb{P}[Y=j]=\frac{e^{-1}}{j!}$$

that is

$$Y\sim Pois(1)$$

$$X\sim Geom\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)$$

---

An easy way to solve the problem was to observe that

$$\mathbb{P}[X=x,Y=y]=\Bigg(\frac{1}{2}\Bigg)^{x}\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{e^{-1}1^y}{y!}=\mathbb{P}[X=x]\times \mathbb{P}[Y=y]$$

$x=\{0;1;2;...\}$

$y=\{0;1;2;...\}$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** You are given that $i,j$ are natural numbers, so $X,Y$ are non-negative integers. To validate this, you need to prove that $\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty f(i,j) = 1$.

Also note that $\mathbb{P}[X=i] = \sum_{j=0}^\infty f(i,j)$...

Comment: but wouldn't we still have $1/e$ for $P(X=i)$

Comment: @AspiringMathematician it will cancel with the sum $\sum 1/j!$